# Why is CORS not being applied in Nestjs applicaiton

Tags: typescript, cors, nestjs

I have this setup for Nestjs app

```
const globalPrefix = 'api';
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const config = app.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService);
  const port = config.get('API_PORT');
  const allowedCors = config.get('CORS_ORIGINS').split(',');

  app.enableCors({ origin: allowedCors });
  app.setGlobalPrefix(globalPrefix);
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.use(helmet());
  app.use(compression());
  app.use(cookieParser());
  // app.use(csurf({ cookie: true }));
  app.use(
    rateLimit({
      windowMs: 15 * 60 * 1000,
      max: config.get('ENV') === 'development' ? Infinity : 100,
    }),
  );
```

Allowed cors is just 1 link for the front-end app, but whenever I try it from another source, it goes through. What am I doing wrong?

The response headers are like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
Date: Sun, 25 Sep 2022 14:44:13 GMT
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 241
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';base-uri 'self';block-all-mixed-content;font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src 'self';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy: same-origin
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
Expect-CT: max-age=0
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Origin-Agent-Cluster: ?1
X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: none
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
X-XSS-Protection: 0
X-RateLimit-Limit: 100
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 97
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1664117909
```

Comment: Could you please provide the significant request/response headers from your dev console.

Comment: I don't know if it is true for your application but in some frameworks, development mode deactivates CORS.

Comment: I updated the question with the response headers. The problem is that I have enabled cors only for some specific ip/domains, but it it allowing from anywhere

Comment: *[...] whenever I try it from another source, it goes through.* Can you be more specific about that? How are you sending those requests? Are you expecting your CORS config to block requests issued from non-browser user agents (like curl and Postman)?

Comment: It clearly goes through in postman, but it also goes through when I make a GET request from the browser (simply copy and paste the url of the get request)

Comment: can you post a CURL of the request? sometimes '/' at the end of the URL can make cors misconfiguration

Answer (score -1):

> It clearly goes through in postman, but it also goes through when I make a GET request from the browser (simply copy and paste the url of the get request)

I think you might misunderstand CORS. Postman does not render any interactive scripts and when you post the URL in the browser address bar, that request is not a cross-domain request.

CORS do not apply to direct GET requests that you actively initiate. CORS is a browser barrier that restricts cross-domain requests in a browser.

As everything is set to `same-origin`, which means only your own site can access your own site via a browser initiated request.

Comment: Yes I think, I misunderstood. In my case I have both the API and frontend app in a server with 2 different subdomains. I'm using nginx for both of them. The I'm trying to allow cors only from the frontend app. Is this configuration enough to stop other apps from different domains from using my API?

Comment: In modern browsers, the default setting (not sending cors) is even sufficient to block browsers from using it through cross-origin requests

Comment: @zedian CORS does not restrict from accessing the API. You need passwords/tokens for that. CORS restricts cross-origin requests through the browser. It's protection for the user who is using the browser, not protection for your API.